# Breaking Loops & re-triggering a variable in a range

Tags: python, loops

Below I am looping through a dictionary -  You can see the 'pages' in , counts how many pages it went through.

```
for pages in range(0,1000)
```

It seems that after the break, the pages value does not reset to 0. This is critical. How can I ensure that it does?

**ANSWER**

```
    numbers = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5}

for key, value in numbers.items():
    print(key)
    for i in range(0, 1000):
        print('-', i)
        if i == value:
            break
```

Comment: Have you tried simply setting `record_job = 0` right before the `break`?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy will that set record_job to zero ?- because record_job is not a variable . think of it as "for i in range"? I do not know./think setting a variable after the loop started would work?

Comment: `record_job` *is* a variable. Python's scope rules mean that it stays in scope even after the loop is over, and at that point its value is whatever it was when the loop was exited. The value of `record_job` would reset itself with every iteration, but it otherwise behaves like any other variable.

Comment: @0004 um, `record_job` is **just a variable**. Like any other. I have no idea why you expect it to reset after you break, but a simple test shows that isn't true.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga could you show this simple test, to avoid any confusion?

Comment: `for i in range(5): print(i)` then outside the loop `print(i)`

Comment: Btw, it's *very bad* practice to just wrap a ton of code that could produce a multitude of different erros with a bare `except: break`...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - Thank you for that, I know that is true, could you help me write a line that would be better? Would it be something like "print exception" . I am new and would like to know how to improve that line.

Comment: Would except "Exception as inst: print(inst)" be better? And should I take out the break? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you do this:

```
for record_job in range(0,1000):
```

`record_job` will successively be set to `0`, `1`, `2`, etc. For example:

```
numbers = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5}

for key, value in numbers.items():
    print(key)
    for i in range(0, 1000):
        print('-', i)
        if i == value:
            break
```

Would prints:

```
one
- 0
- 1
two
- 0
- 1
- 2
three
- 0
- 1
- 2
- 3
four
- 0
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
five
- 0
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
```

But if `i` was then to be printed outside of the loops like so:

```
numbers = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5}

for key, value in numbers.items():
    print(key)
    for i in range(0, 1000):
        print('-', i)
        if i == value:
            break
print(i)
```

It would prints `5` because it was the last value `i` was assigned to for the current scope. Which is what I assume you noticed. If you want to clear i for the current scope, then you should delete it after your loops are done:

```
numbers = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5}

for key, value in numbers.items():
    print(key)
    for i in range(0, 1000):
        print('-', i)
        if i == value:
            break
del i
print(i) # NameError, i is no longer defined
```

That said, you should not name your dictionary `dict` because by doing so, you are shadowing a builtin and this is not good practice.

Comment: Briere, so why does my code above, when changing dict. values, not restart at zero rather continues?